# Nested class from a string

Tags: ruby, nested-class

I want to call a method on a class in the namespace of `Publishers`, such as `Publishers::Vk`, where the nested part is expressed as a string like `provider_name = 'Vk'`. I did something like that:

```
send("Publishers::#{provider_name}.new(#{@photo})")
```

I get an exception:

```
undefined method `Publishers::Vk.new(#<Photo:0x000000085e5440>)' for #<PhotoPublisher:0x00000008616c98>
```

How can I implement this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Publishers.const_get(provider_name).new(@photo)
```

Comment: Yes, exactly, it's a constant